# Web Application in IBM Bluemix

Tags: python, ibm-cloud

We want to deploy an existing application in IBM Bluemix. Using Python command prompt we have pushed the application in IBM Bluemix, but when we deploy it in IBM, it won't work. It is giving the following errors:

> Creating container Successfully created container Downloading app
>   package... Downloaded app package (1.5K) Staging... Downloaded build
>   artifacts cache (31.3M) None of the buildpacks detected a compatible
>   application Exit status 222 Staging failed: Exited with status 222
>   Destroying container
>
> FAILED Error restarting application: NoAppDetectedError
>              TIP: Buildpacks are detected when the "cf push" is executed from within the directory that contains the app source code.
>
> Use 'cf buildpacks' to see a list of supported buildpacks.
>
> Use 'cf logs glucose_tracker_monitor --recent' for more in depth log
>   information.
>
> Finished: FAILED

I don't know what to do after this. Can anyone help me with these errors?

Comment: Have you mentioned buildpack in the manifest.yml file? Are you using this buildpack? https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python

Comment: Can you please add you code and directory structure of your application? You should have at least the python file in the directory structure so the buildpack can detect it and push your application to Bluemix.

Answer (score 2):

The message "None of the buildpacks detected a compatible application" means that none of the buildpacks installed in Bluemix have recognized your project as a project that they can run.

From the Bluemix documentation for the [Python buildpack](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/python/index.html), your application needs to include either a "setup.py" or "requirements.txt" file to make this buildpack "detect" your application as something that it can run.

The "requirements.txt" file is used to specify any pip packages that your application needs to be installed.  For an example, see the [requirements.txt](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/get-started-python/blob/master/requirements.txt) file in the "get-started-python" project in the "IBM-Bluemix" GitHub repository.

Your application should also include a file named "Procfile" which will specify how the buildpack should start your application.

Example "Procfile":

```
web: python hello.py
```

This would cause the buildpack to run the command `python hello.py` when starting the application.

Comment: thank you so much. i tried this and i got it. !! now it is not showing that error and i can deploy my application in IBM bluemix.

Comment: Accept this answer, Arha.

Comment: why web: ?
are there any other options?